# Why the type of a class is <class 'type'>

Tags: python, class, types

I was checking type of every thing in python. But I could not understand why the type of a class is `<class 'type'>`

```
class Hello:
    pass


c = Hello
print('type check one: ', type(c))
print('type check two: ', type(Hello))
```

output:-
type check one:  <class 'type'>
type check two:  <class 'type'>

Answer (score 3):

[`type` is a metaclass in Python](https://realpython.com/python-metaclasses/#:%7E:text=type%20is%20a%20metaclass%2C%20of,instance%20of%20the%20type%20metaclass.&text=type%20is%20also%20an%20instance,is%20an%20instance%20of%20itself.)

A metaclass is just a class of a class, [as explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-are-metaclasses-in-python).

Because you did not specify what type of object `c` was, and instead said it is just a `Hello` class, `Hello` inherits from `type`, thus making it of a `type` class.